# Carousel control stopped working

Tags: php, jquery, html, css, carousel

My Carousel controls suddenly stopped working. This is not my page and I'm not expert in web design so I don't know much about functionality. I'm only adding new stuffs to this page. Until tonight everything was fine and now Carousel controls are not even working.
Carousel is at top of the page : http://makovi.ba/

Code of slider.php is here = http://pastebin.com/P1wRiqUs

I would really appreciate help.

Ty in advance

Comment: bootstrap.min.js file is missing.

http://makovi.ba/assets/js/bootstrap.min.js Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)

Comment: What @Paresh said. More specifically, the bootstrap.min.js file needs to be added back into the assets/js directory - it's physically missing

Comment: yes this js file is required for carousel

Comment: Thank you guys very much now it's working. Awesome

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using firebug it says bootstrap.js wasn't loaded:

`<script src="assets/js/bootstrap.min.js">`  **404 Not Found** The resource requested could not be found on this server!

Try to put the full path to the bootstrap.js or insert it properly and it should work

Comment: Thank you very much you are awesome

Comment: happens to me all the time :D